# "Ambiguity between X and X" for every property after modifying entity model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I'm getting "Ambiguity between 'XYZ.EntityX.PropertyX' and 'XYZ.EntityX.PropertyX'" errors on every reference to properties in my entity model after making a small change to it and attempting to recompile. Both properties are identical in every case. There are also a lot of "The type 'XYZ.EntityX' already contains a definition for 'PropertyX'". Has anyone run into anything like this before?

I recently put the code into source safe, which I'll take a wild guess and say may have something to do with it. Maybe it cant update a file that's not checked out and also isnt prompting about it? I have no idea.

All I did was go into XYZModel.edmx, select a table, add a scalar property (string, 50 chars, nullable) and recompile. Everything worked until then. It also happens when I 'Update model from database'. I'm guessing any change at all to the model will cause it.

Comment: The errors should tell you the location of your two duplicate files.

Comment: does XYZ inherit from another entity type?

Comment: I have an XYZModel.cs and an EntityX.cs, both defining the same properties for EntityX. But why would it do that? It's always limited its poor decisions to things like trying to do inserts on views. It never created duplicate properties until now

Comment: are you saying you have a class defined via EDMX ObjectContext *and* a class defined using the DbContext tt's?

Comment: I think I found it. The individual Entity.cs files weren't checked out. I think it was duplicating everything in XYZModel.cs because it couldnt write to those. Working through one more error but that seems to have been the cause of the other 380. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: This sometimes happens when you renamed incorrectly.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem in Visual Studio 2015 but I used TFS instead of Sourcesafe.

First option is to make sure you are connected to your Source Control (Online).

If that doesn't work

1. Make sure your Visual Studio solution is connected to TFS/Source Control. This issue can occur when your offline mode. Right click on the solution and select Go Online if your offline.
2. Once your online connected to TFS in Visual Studio right click on the edmx and select Goto Source Control->Undo Pending changes. This will undo all the pending changes for the edmx  and the associated generated files.
3. Delete the changed table from the edmx and add it again.
4. Build your solution

Comment: such a drag, best to never used Refresh again but simply drop whole table and then re-add it

Comment: Dropping 20+ tables did nothing for me. A simple "Go online" fixed it all.

Comment: Go Online worked for me too

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. For some reason when updating my Entity Framework model it had created a second Model.Context.cs file.

This seemed to be because the original one had become disconnected from the model and it had to create a new one. I deleted the **original** one and it fixed the issue.

These .cs files should be visible in the Solution Explorer by finding the Model.edmx expanding out then finding and expanding out the Context.tt file.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same error just now and i found out that i had copied classes to a new folder and not changes their names.

I have a Folder name `Group` and `City`, i then copied classes from `Group` to `City` when `Group` and `City` folders are referenced on the appservice i'm getting errors from.

Answer (score 0):

I think you move or copy some file to other folder so they appear this error!