# Error CS0229 Ambiguity between 'CreateModel._context' and 'CreateModel._context'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have completed following the tutorial at: [Tutorial: Create a Razor Pages web app with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

After finishing it I decided to add Reviews to the Movies (just to learn). As such I added a new Review class to my Models folder:

```
public class Review
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The Title must be less than {1} characters.")]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 5)]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Then inside my 'Pages' folder I created a new one called 'Reviews' and I right-clicked -> Add -> New scaffolded Item.
After selecting *Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)* I added the following details as seen on the picture:
[image: Add Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)]

My problem is that after VS generates the appropriate code, the application does not compile because it gives decades of errors like:

```
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'CreateModel._context' and 'CreateModel._context' RazorPagesMovie
```

Can someone please let me know of why that error is popping up?

**Edit:**
After the scaffolding I observed that I have same file names (and classes on my solution). For example I have the *CreateModel* class that was auto-generated by scaffolding declared twice (once for the Movies & once for the Reviews):

[image: File structure]

**Edit 2:**
It seems that both CreateModel classes (for Movies & Reviews) have exactly the same namespace (namespace RazorPagesMovie). Shouldn't they be something like:
*namespace RazorPagesMovie.Pages.Movies*
and
*namespace RazorPagesMovie.Pages.Reviews*
accordingly?

Comment: Check this question, maybe you are facing same issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666646/ambiguity-between-x-and-x-for-every-property-after-modifying-entity-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a known problem in Visual Studio that while Scaffolding the namespace is not generated correctly.

Links:

[Namespace problem when generating Razor Pages in VS 2019](https://forums.asp.net/t/2162302.aspx?Namespace%20problem%20when%20generating%20Razor%20Pages%20in%20VS%202019)

[Scaffolding incorrect namespace](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/822390/scaffolding-incorrect-namespace.html)

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue after copying and pasting a ViewModel into a new folder.

Closed VS and re-opened it. All errors disappeared and I was able to build again.

Answer (score 1):

I also had these error messages.
The reason is that I made a copy of a code file and left this copy in the same folder. To Visual Studio, all functions in the copy were duplicates and VS got confused.

As soon as I moved the backup code file to another location, the errors went away!